# Создание сетки на CSS

Tags: css3

Может кто-то подсказать, как сделать такие серые линии?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таблица?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  padding: 20px;
}
div{
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><div>100</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>200</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>300</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>400</div>Ячейка</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div>500</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>600</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>700</div>Ячейка</td>
    <td><div>800</div>Ячейка</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```